# Get Assembly Version in Pure XAML GetExecutingAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, system.reflection

Is it possible to load the Assembly Version in a pure XAML code?
I've found this here:

http://www.widecodes.com/0mHWVVkWeV/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-textblocks-text-to-an-applications-assemblyversion.html

But it always Returns 4.0.0

```
<TextBlock xmlns:ref="clr-namespace:System.Reflection;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Version">
            <Binding.Source>
                <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetName">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetExecutingAssembly"
                                            ObjectType="{x:Type ref:Assembly}" />
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Then i tried this here: (which works perfect if the App runs)

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column="0" xmlns:ref="clr-namespace:System.Reflection;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Version">
            <Binding.Source>
                <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetName">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom"
                                            ObjectType="{x:Type ref:Assembly}">
                            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                                <sys:String>.\Modules\Myassembly.dll</sys:String>
                            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                        </ObjectDataProvider>
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But now the Designer says (wants to find the Assembly in System32)

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\system32\Modules\MyAssembly.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
```

Comment: Thanks LightBulb for reviewing the layout

Answer (score 4):

Try using GetEntryAssembly instead of GetExecutingAssembly with the first example.  For me this shows up as 14.0.0.0 in the designer, but is correct when the application runs.

```
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetName">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
            <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetEntryAssembly" ObjectType="{x:Type ref:Assembly}" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```